# Compute $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_t]$, where $\tilde{X}_t=X_t=(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}dW_s$ for $0\le t<1$ and $\tilde{X}_t=0$ for $t=1$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following exercise and I don't really understand the answer. I am going to write my professor's answer first, then a question about what I don't understand about my professor's answer and my attempt at the end. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot in advance!

**QUESTION:** Compute $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_t]$, where $\tilde{X}_t=X_t=(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}dW_s$ for $0\le t<1$ and $\tilde{X}_t=0$ for $t=1$.

**PROFESSOR'S ANSWER:**

Note that
$$\int_0^t\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)^2 ds=\frac{1}{1-t}<\infty \quad\text{for all }t\in[0,1)$$
Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s} dW_s\right]=0\implies \mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_t]=0\quad\text{for all }t\in[0,1)$$
and since $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_t]=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.

**MY QUESTION:**

**1. Why does the first integral imply that $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s} dW_s\right]=0$?**

**MY ATTEMPT:**

$$\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_t]=(1-t)\mathbb{E}\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}dW_s=(1-t)\mathbb{E}\frac{W_t}{1-t}=\mathbb{E}W_t=0\quad\text{for all }t\in\mathbb{R}$$
Hence, $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_t]=0$ for $t\in[0,1].$

**2. Would this be correct?**

Comment: @ s1047857 : hi your attempt is simply totally false. Your professor is right but he doesn't explain why he calculates the first integral, the reason for doing this is the fact that for the stochastic integral to exist it suffices that the square of the integrand be Lebesgue integrable and moreover in that case it is a true martingale which implies that its value is 0. Best regards

Comment: Actually, $\int_0^t\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)^2 ds=\frac{t}{1-t}.$

Answer (score 2):

1. Your attempt: How do you conclude that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s}  \, dW_s \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{W_t}{1-t} \right)$$ ...? To me it looks as you used something of the form $$\int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s = f(t) W_t,$$ but this identity is, in general, **not** correct.
2. Your professor's answer: Your professor uses the following well-known theorem:

   > Let $f : [0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a progressively-measurable function such that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds \right) <\infty$$ for all $t \geq 0$. Then the stochastic integral $$M_t := \int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$$ is well-defined for all $t \geq 0$. Moreover, $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale; in particular, $$\mathbb{E}(M_t) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)=0.$$

   In your setting the function $f$ is determinstic, i.e. $f$ does not depend on $\omega$. Therefore, it suffices to check that $f$ is Borel-measurable (which it is) and  that the integrability condition $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds \right)  = \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$$ is satisfied. That's exactly what your professor did.